# MultiValueDictKeyError: 'file_URL' on passing a URL

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, forms

I have a form which contains a file upload but I am not uploading file through that, I store it into firebase storage then pass the URL through ajax request. I found the error - The request is being made before my image is even uploaded to storage and I get url, therefore blank request is passed. Is there a way to fix it ?

In my views.py I got -:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    title = request.POST['title']
    time = request.POST['time']
    description = request.POST['description']
    file_URL = request.POST['file_URL']
    date = request.POST['date']
```

The error occurs on `file_URL = request.POST['file_URL']`

As it says django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'file_URL'

In my template I have a very simple form -

```
<form id="create-assignment">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="title-time-wrapper">
        <input type="text" name="assignment-title" id="assignment-title-input" required class="assignment-form-input" placeholder="Title" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="text" name="assignment-time" class="assignment-form-input" id="assignment-time-input" required placeholder="Time" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <textarea rows="5" cols="40" name="progress" id="assignment-description-input" required class="assignment-form-input" placeholder="Description" autocomplete="off"></textarea>
    <input type="file" name="files[]" id="assignment-file-input">
    <input type="submit" class="submit-btn" value="Save" id="assignment-form-submit">
</form>
```

And finally for my Javascript -:

```
 var file, file_URL
 var storage = firebase.storage();
 var storageref = storage.ref('Assignments').child('test');

 $(document).on('submit', '#create-assignment', function(e){
        let today = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10)
        file = document.getElementById("assignment-file-input").files[0];
        var thisref=storageref.child(file.name).put(file);
        thisref.on('state_changed',function(snapshot) {
                console.log('Done');
            }, function(error) {
                console.log('Error',error);
            }, function() {
            // Uploaded completed successfully, now we can get the download URL
            thisref.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
                file_URL = downloadURL;
            });
        });
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/teacher/exam/create/',
            data:{
                title: $('#assignment-title-input').val(),
                time: $('#assignment-time-input').val(),
                description: $('#assignment-description-input').val(),
                file_URL: file_URL,
                date: today,
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
            }
        });
        $('#create-assignment').trigger("reset"); 
});
```

This is an example URL - [image]

I found a few solutions but all of them were for django forms asking to change 'enctype' if anyone could help that would be really helpful.

Comment: on your ajax call  `data: { fileURL: file_URL}` should be `{file_URL: file_URL}` right?

Comment: ohh sorry, but the same problem continues

Comment: @engin_ipek I found the error, my ajax request is getting called immediately on submit even before I get url for image. I want to submit once I get url. but i don't want a separate upload button and submit button. Is there a way to do so ?

Comment: Hi, put ajax call after `console.log('Done');` so it will execute after getting url . Else call one function from there and put your ajax call code there .